# When I add favorites I can't see them

Tags: support, bookmarks

I'm trying to review my favorites but the more recent (added 20 minutes ago, or on the same day) doesn't displays, someone knows why maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You've got](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9817602/webman?tab=favorites&sort=newest&page=1) [3 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9817602/webman?tab=favorites&sort=newest&page=2) [of favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9817602/webman?tab=favorites&sort=newest&page=3). By default they're not sorted by when you added them but by their votes or last activity. So I suspect that the "disappearing" ones are on the other pages.

Comment: Okay I have used the "newest" feature and didn't found them but I will double check

Comment: @Webman Have you checked the other pages? Specifically, [these](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9817602/webman?tab=favorites&sort=newest&page=2) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9817602/webman?tab=favorites&sort=newest&page=3)? If you have then I'll promptly delete this answer.

Comment: Okay I see... so newest target the last active pages it seems, and no the date of their adding in the user profile

Comment: if you want yes, thank you

Comment: @Webman there, done.

Comment: I don't know how do an undownvote ^^'

Comment: Ah, you just click either the downvote button again to retract it, or the upvote button to change it to an upvote.

Comment: it returns me "you can't vote on your own posts", anyway  thanks even^^

Comment: Oh, I was referring to my answer.

Comment: ok ok ^^ I understand better now, your answer is upvoted by me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180010/discussion-between-stephen-leppik-and-webman).